# Projector does only affect model

Tags: unity, projection

I'm working on a simple selection of a RTS unit. Therefore I used a projector to display a circle on the ground around the unit.
But it happened, that the circle is only displayed on the head of the unit-placeholder, not on the ground.

At first I thought it has something to do with the terrain, but as I added a Plane there was'nt a change.

I followed the steps from this tutorial: http://hyunkell.com/blog/rts-style-unit-selection-in-unity-5/ (skipped the drag box part)

Here's a screenshot from the scene:

[image]

I'm wondering how I can solve this. I'll provide every information you'll need.

Comment: Does the projector frustrum actually hit the ground?